# Pythonでスクレイピングできない（一部しかできない）ページがあるので理由と取得方法を知りたい

Tags: python, python3, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Pythonでスクレイピングできない（一部しかできない）ページがある。
コードは下記の通り。
（progateのclass指定のあるh3タグの取得を実行している）

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://prog-8.com/"

res = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')


h = soup.find_all("h3", class_ = "landing-heading landing-lesson-intro__small-section-title right-spacer")
print(h)
```

結果はリストで[]となる。（None）
ピンポイントにh3のclassを指定しているのに取得できない。
取得できない理由と取得する方法を教えてほしい。

Comment: 該当Webページのソースを見ると`h3`関連は`<h3>Progate</h3>`しか存在しないようですが。

Comment: Chromeの開発者ツールで確認すると対象のタグは存在していますがrequestsで取得した中身を確認すると確かにh3しか存在していません。

Comment: この部分です。→
<h3 class="landing-heading landing-lesson-intro__small-section-title right-spacer">イラスト中心のスライドで学ぶ</h3>

Comment: スクリプト等で後から差し込まれるのでは？ Selenium+WebDriverに切り替えてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: JavaScriptで生成されているようでした。Seleniumで試してみます。